# Reading an unknown number of inputs

Tags: java, c++, input

I need to read an unknown number of inputs using either C++ or Java. Inputs have exactly two numbers per line. I'd need to use `cin` or a `System.in` `Scanner` because input comes from the console, not from a file.

Example input:

```
1 2

3 4

7 8

100 200

121 10
```

I want to store the values in a vector. I have no idea how many pairs of numbers I have. How do I design a `while` loop to read the numbers so I can put them into a vector?

Comment: Is there an indicator of the last non-inclusive input via a sentinel value? (Usually a non-nonsensical value like -999 or EOF)

Comment: @Casey No. Every number is inclusive. The user presses Enter twice in a row when he finishes entering the inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an idiomatic `std::copy` in C++: ([see it work here with virtualized input strings](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4e3022a35088da2ac80b8628fbd97a59))

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::copy (
    std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
    std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
    std::back_inserter(vec)
);
```

That way, it will append onto the vector each time an integer is read from the input stream until it fails reading, whether from bad input or EOF.

Comment: I presume the fact they're paired is significant

Comment: @MooingDuck, True, you could have a wrapper that controls back insertions to first go to one element of a pair, then to the other, then to the first of a new pair. You could also take my `vec` and use it to fill in a vector of pairs once all of the data has been read.

Comment: I attempted to extend this answer using `pair`, but it turns out `std::cout >> mypair` won't use my overload, due to ADL.  So you'd have to use a custom struct.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Looks good. I'm not sure why I didn't pick up on just inputting both values in each go...

Answer (score 4):

Java:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputLine;
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
  inputLine = sc.nextLine();
  //parse inputLine however you want, and add to your vector
}
```

Comment: Loop is going on indefinitely. what i am doing is i put inputLine in ArrayList one by one. How to stop this loop?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a buffered reader, one can use Scanner as follows to accomplish the same

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        String Line = new String(scan.nextLine());
        if(Line.length()==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Only workaround I found    :

```
import java.io.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int i=1 ;
        String line =br.readLine();
        while(line.length()>0){
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for less fancier C++ code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    int main(){
        std::vector<int>inputs;  //any container
        for(int i;std::cin>>i;)  //here the magic happens
            inputs.push_back(i); //press Ctrl+D to break the loop
        for(int num:inputs)      //optional 
            std::cout<<num<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: You forgot the namespace scope for endl. Ctrl-d is platform-dependent. Asker says "user presses Enter twice in a row when he finishes entering the inputs" in a comment. Your program does not recognize this condition.